# "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" occuring while trying to set an array element

Tags: java, out-of-memory

This is a chunk of code I'm using for Google's antai challenge whenever I run it it seems to go into some endless loop then I get the stack trace at the bottom. I'm burnt out looking at this code I can't for the life of me figure this out.

```
public class Node 
{
    private final int xCoord, yCoord;
    private int F, G, H;
    private Tile location;
    Node previousNode;
    private Tile [] neighbors;

    /*  
    G 
    the exact cost to reach this node from the starting node.
    H 
    the estimated(heuristic) cost to reach the destination from here.
    F = G + H 
    As the algorithm runs the F value of a node tells us how expensive we think it will         be to reach our goal by way of that node.
    */

    public Node(Tile loc)
    {
        location = loc;
        xCoord = location.getCol();
        yCoord = location.getRow();
        F=G=H=0;
        setNeighbors();
    }

    private void setNeighbors()
    {
        if(neighbors == null)
        {
            neighbors = new Tile[4];
        }
        neighbors[0] = new Tile(xCoord+1,yCoord);
        neighbors[1] = new Tile(xCoord-1,yCoord);
        neighbors[2] = new Tile(xCoord,yCoord+1);
        neighbors[3] = new Tile(xCoord,yCoord-1);//error occurs here!!!!!!
    }
}

        /**
 * Represents a tile of the game map.
 */
public class Tile implements Comparable<Tile> {
    private final int row;

    private final int col;

    /**
     * Creates new {@link Tile} object.
     * 
     * @param row row index
     * @param col column index
     */
    public Tile(int row, int col) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
    }

    /**
     * Returns row index.
     * 
     * @return row index
     */
    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    /**
     * Returns column index.
     * 
     * @return column index
     */
    public int getCol() {
        return col;
    }

    /** 
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Tile o) {
        return hashCode() - o.hashCode();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return row * Ants.MAX_MAP_SIZE + col;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (o instanceof Tile) {
            Tile tile = (Tile)o;
            result = row == tile.row && col == tile.col;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return row + " " + col;
    }
    }
```

the actual error I'm receiving is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at Node.setNeighbors(Node.java:37)
    at Node.<init>(Node.java:25)
    at AstarSearch.assessRoute(AstarSearch.java:73)
    at MyBot.gatherFood(MyBot.java:153)
    at MyBot.doTurn(MyBot.java:124)
    at AbstractSystemInputParser.processLine(AbstractSystemInputParser.java:54)
    at AbstractSystemInputReader.readSystemInput(AbstractSystemInputReader.java:18)
    at MyBot.main(MyBot.java:25)
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: You haven't shown us your Tile code - in particular, the constructor.

Comment: Have you tried attaching with a profiler and seeing what objects are leaking?  VishalVM ships with the JDK.

Comment: what is the size of data that you are processing? are you sure you are not genuinely out of heap space ? like Jon pointed out, the code shown is just a plain bean, what do you do in Tile's constructor ? also, take a heap dump using jmap and see what's occupying space, this is not a stack overflow error, its OOM for heap, so you are most probably creating more objects than the space provided.

Comment: sorry about that... tile attached now

Comment: Also please show AstarSearch.    I daresay that endless loop is there. Nothing criminal  so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what this Google challenge is, so this may not be of much use (ie I don't know if you have access to the JVM), though it is a generic method to help diagnose this kind of problem.

I suggest turning on the JVM flag `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`, and running your code again. An OutOfMemoryError will cause the heap to be dumped. You can then analyse this offline using something like [Eclipse MAT](http://eclipse.org/mat/).

Answer (score 3):

You need to do some debugging / clean up.     From quick view I see, that in assesRoute() you
are never manipulating interesetedNode tile - this loop is not going to end  normally.

It is also better to keep visited nodes in hash set -  you only need to assure presence or absence, not a number of nodes. Alternative would  be boolean flag in a node itself, this way you can work it with one list.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your creating more objects than your memory allows, guess your code is including an unfifite loop, you can make a static integer to count how many times the setNeighbors is called, its the routine where you create new objects, and show this integer on the catch statement of a try/catch around the main call of your class.

Answer (score 0):

The MyBot.doTurn() in the stack trace suggests your program is running over or discovering some kind of path... Are you sure this is a finite algorithm?

Comment: no im not actually sure what you mean this is a very amateur attempt/ first try at ai programming so im in slightly over my head i would just, for now like to get this error out of the way so i can see if my idea has worked... for the entire code you can check github.com/absolutelysmokinsoftware

Answer (score 0):

in assesRoute is a while loop. how many iterations do you expect? print out how many are actually done. if the difference is big, you know that there is a problem. take the start state of this iteration and try to understand why this state doesn't end the loop in proper time.